# python 配車問題

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

pythonを最近学習し始めた者です。
pythonを使用してやりたいことがあるのですが、キーワードがわからない為、やり方を検索できずにいます。

以下やりたい内容となります。

やりたいこと：ある地域の中に３つのタクシー会社があるとします。（会社A・会社B・会社C）各会社の所有タクシー数は、[会社A：２台][会社B：２台][会社C：１台]
タクシーを呼ぶ人は地域内の建物にいることとし、タクシー会社から地域内の各建物までの距離はあらかじめ別のcsvファイルで作成してあります。
タクシーを呼ぶ人がいた時、タクシーを呼んだ人がいる建物に近い会社からタクシーを配車させることを繰り返した時に、タクシーがすべて出払っている会社が出るといった事象が起きることが考えられますが、そういった場合に、タクシーを呼んだ人のいる建物から近く、タクシーの残っている会社からタクシーを配車する場合にはpythonのどのような機能を使用すればよいでしょうか。
３つの会社のタクシー数＜タクシーを呼ぶ人の数
とし、全タクシー会社のタクシーがすべて配車されるまで繰り返すものとします。

このような内容をpythonで構築したい場合、どのようなキーワードで検索、どのような構文で構築するのが良いのでしょうか。
初歩的なことをお聞きし申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考: [Taxi Dispatch Simulator](https://github.com/carsonluuu/Real-Time-Taxi-Dispatch-Simulator)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/219651

Comment: この質問で想定しているのは、metropolis さんが提示したような「既存のアルゴリズム、解法が何か存在しないか」ですか？それとも「Pythonの文法」等についてでしょうか？ / 仮に後者の場合、基礎的な部分はある程度ご自身で理解した状態でないと、回答しなければいけない範囲が定まらない気がします。

Comment: 「タクシーを呼ぶ」というのが同時に起きないという制約と、「ある建物から一番近いタクシー会社は一意に決まる(同じ距離に複数のタクシー会社は無い)」という制約をつければ、比較的簡単に解けそうに思います。タクシーを呼ぶ人に順序を付けて、順番に従ってタクシーを割り当てれば良いだけですから。　何が判らないのですか？？？

Comment: Fumu7さん>最初そのように考えていたのですが、処理を行っているうちに一番近いタクシー会社にタクシーが存在しないという事象が発生してしまうかと思います。そうした場合には、一番近いタクシー会社からではなく２番目に近いタクシー会社からタクシーを派遣させようと考えていたのですが、『一番近いタクシー会社にタクシーがいない場合に、二番目に近いタクシー会社から派遣させる』という部分をどのように表現したらよいかわからずに困っております。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

アルゴリズムとしては、[貪欲法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B2%AA%E6%AC%B2%E6%B3%95)で配車問題を解きたいという話だと感じました。

具体的には、次のように問題を抽象化して：

```
resource[i] : 会社 i の所有タクシー数
cost[i][j] : 建物 i から会社 j までの距離
jobs[i] : i 番目の呼び出しで呼ばれた先の建物
```

これに対し「タクシーが残っている会社 (`cost[i][j] > 0` な会社 `j`) の中で距離が最短の会社 (`cost[job[i]][j]` が最小の会社 `j`) 」を順番に割り当てていく手順です。

疑似的にプログラムを書くとこのような感じです：

```py
result = [-1] * len(jobs)
for i, job in enumerate(jobs):
    # 最短の会社を見つける
    nearest = -1
    min_cost = float("inf")
    for company, r in enumerate(resource):
        if r > 0 and cost[job][company] < min_cost:
            nearest = company
            min_cost = cost[job][company]
    if nearest == -1:
        # もうタクシーが残っていない
        break
    # 見つけた会社に割り振る
    resource[nearest] -= 1
    result[i] = nearest
```

Comment: 元となるcsvファイル[ファイル名：all_date]（すべての会社からすべての建物までの所要時間を求めたもの）の中身[company_ID,buildingsID,total_time][1,137,0.1232][2,137,0.2862][3,137,0.2973][1,30,0.2476][2,30,0.1216][3,30,0.234]......があるとき、タクシーを呼んだ人list[buildings_id,total_time(totaltimeは空欄)][137,  ][163, ].....がある時に、近いタクシー会社からタクシーを呼ぶときには、mergeを使えばよいと思いますが、各タクシー会社のタクシー所有数に制限がある（company_ID1：１台,company_ID2：２台,company_ID：２台）時にどのように制限を加えればよいでしょうか。

Comment: タクシー会社のタクシー台数に上限を設けない場合には以下のスクリプトで元ととcsvファイルより最短距離が求まると思います。

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("all_date.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("list.csv")
results = df.merge(df2,on="buildings_ID")

Comment: 実行時間を気にしなければこの回答と同じように解決できます。pandasっぽく解決するならBoolean array indexingを一緒に使えばできそうです。

Answer (score 0):

恐らく、「クラス」や「オブジェクト指向」について勉強すると良いと思います。

「Python　クラス　使い方」などで検索しましょう。

Daaaaai39さんのやりたいことは、タクシー会社A、タクシー会社B、タクシー会社Cという「クラス」を作る（正確には、タクシー会社クラスを作り、A,B,Cそれぞれの会社の値で初期化して使う）ことで、非常に分かりやすく、応用できる形で解けるようになります。

恐らく蛇足だと思いますが、他には二次元ベクトルの計算が必要なので、「二次元ベクトル　距離」等での検索もされると良いでしょう。このような計算は、メソッドとしてクラスに実装すると良いです。